# What RDBMS optimizations can we do for append-only tables?

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, database-design, immutability

Let's say we have a table which saves immutable events. This table does not support any UPDATE statements, just INSERT and SELECT.

I can imagine that there are some optimizations we can make for such tables, since there will never be a case where a row is being updated while another query reads it. Is there a looser transaction isolation we can set? Are there any other optimizations we can do?

I understand that the optimizations may depend on the specific database. In that case, I would suggest focusing on Postgres and/or MySQL as they are the most common in my experience.

Comment: The question is too wide. Please narrow it down a bit. What do you want to optimize? Insert performance, querying performance, concurrency, load, etc. Do you need up-to-the-second results, or 1-hour old stale results are OK?

Comment: What are the indexes?  Is one of them `AUTO_INCREMENT`?  Are the `INSERTs` only on the "end" of the table?  Will `SELECTs` never look at the "end" of the table?

Answer (score 2):

You might not need to deal with tuples being updated while being read, but still have to deal with being incompletely inserted, or completely inserted but not committed, or inserted but then rolled back, all while being read.  Needing to deal with those correctly will greatly limit any scope for optimization.